# 1/4 Symmetry Model in abaqus

Tags: abaqus

[image]
I have a full 3D model of a  Test Specimen. I want to use Symmetry condition and model only 1/4 of the model so that I can save calculation Time. I apply Displacements on the Nodes at center of Specimen and calculate the Forces acting on the Model from a Reference Point in space Using MPC constraint,I calculate Forces from the right hand side. The other end of the specimen is fixed. I want to ask what Boundary Conditions should I apply to the Model ?. The original distance between the two nodes where I Give displacements is 30 mm.Should I also change that distance between the nodes while Modelling 1/4 Model?. Thanks in Advance for Your Help......

Comment: my advice if you are new at this, make a full 3d model, then set up the quarter model and validate that you get the exact same results.  Your description is hard to follow without a picture..

Comment: I have added a picture of my specimen..

Comment: The displacement condition is fairly obvious, the same as for the full model. assuming you originally pull symmetrically left&right, or half if you originality fix one end and pull the other.  Its not clear what you are doing with MPC but if you are talking about dummy nodes their absolute position/distance is irrelevant, only displacments go into the constraint equation.